# Can I use same physical L2 switch for separate networks?

Tags: networking, routing, switch, vlan

I have IT background but limited networking knowledge. The question is for my home network:

Right now I have 2 Wi-Fi routers/DHCP servers (Home 10.20.30.1 & Guest 172.20.30.1) connected physically to my ISP modem/router (192.168.10.x). The Home router is then physically connected to the L2 switch and the Home LAN (10.20.30.x), while the Guest router is only for wifi use. My question is whether I can somehow use the switch (L2) to physically connect the ISP router, the Home router/DHCP server, the Home LAN and the Guest router/DHCP server without any hickups and ensuring the isolation between Home and Guest LAN's. Is this something that needs to be done via a VLAN's and how is this setup?

[image: Proposed Home LAN]

Comment: If the switch has VLAN support, then yes. If not, no.

Comment: The switch can be L2, but you need separate VLANs. With only one switch you don't need any port to be tagged and the VLAN can even be "port based".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLAN's can accomplish what you are trying to do. In fact, the 'Cisco blessed architectures' suggest exactly what you are saying; having the ISP connect to a switch which then bridges to the local router.  It requires a VLAN-supporting switch, and an 8 port semi-managed switch runs about $10/port.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. I have an HP ProCurve 1810G-24 switch that supports VLAN's. From my limited understanding, seems that (a) I need to configure 2 VLAN's, one for each Home and Guest, and (b) Assign the ports of each wired device to the appropriate VLAN. 
Can someone shed some light on the Tag/Untag/Exclude All setting, please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those switches, but since your router aren't (knowingly) participating in VLANs, you'll want all your ports to be 'untagged'.  This means that the port is limited to just the specified VLAN, but the connected devices do not have to be VLAN-aware.